# SQL Server 2000 - Breaking out of a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not good at SQL Server 2000. I have a comma-delimited list of ids. I need to see if that ID exists in a table. If it does, I want to break out of the loop with that ID saved in a variable that I can use in my stored procedure. This is what I am trying right now:

```
DECLARE @coreID INT
SET @coreID=NULL

DECLARE @itemID NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE itemCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT [String] AS 'itemID' FROM dbo.SplitListIntoTable(@myIDs)

OPEN itemCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM itemCursor INTO @itemID
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

  -- If @itemID EXISTS IN MyTable set @coreID=@itemID and Break. How do I do this?

  FETCH NEXT FROM itemCursor INTO @itemID
END

CLOSE itemCursor
DEALLOCATE itemCursor
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you shouldn't use a cursor as performance won't be great. If you can do it as a set-based statement, do that instead, maybe like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @CoreID = [String] 
FROM dbo.SplitListIntoTable(@myIDs) x
    JOIN MyTable t ON x.[String] = t.ID
```

However, if you have a real reason to use a cursor, you can use the [BREAK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260676(SQL.80).aspx) statement to break out of a WHILE loop

e.g.

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @ItemID)
            BEGIN
                SET @CoreId = @ItemId
                BREAK
            END        

        FETCH NEXT FROM itemCursor INTO @itemID
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this using a cursor, but I supect you can do this much better (faster) with a a join. If the output of dbo.SplitListIntoTable(@myIDs) is actually an odered table, then you can output a table with another column what is say the string numer, 1, 2, 3, etc...

(I don't have sql in front of me to test this but something like)

```
create table t(itemNum int identity, itemId nvarchar(max))

insert into t (item id) select 1 from dbo.SplitListIntoTable(@myIDs)
```

Then join the two and take the top one

```
set @coreID = 
select top 1 @itemID 
from MyTable m
inner join t t.itemid = m.itemid
order by m.itemNum asc
```

of course you could use a CTE, table var or temp table too.