# Can any one explain how break the cursor manually in sql server and with any sample example code

Tags: sql-server, cursor

1) Can any one explain how break the cursor manually in sql server 
2) any sample example code.

Comment: What do you mean by "break a cursor".  Exit from a cursor loop?  Cause an error during cursor fetch?

Comment: Yes,i need   when condition false "Exit from a cursor loop"

Comment: The best approach would be to avoid the cursor in the first place.

Comment: the thousands of samples you can find with a google search didn't help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2000 - Breaking out of a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394076/sql-server-2000-breaking-out-of-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

> use variable to stop the loop

```
    declare @exit bit=1 --change it to 0 inside the loop to 'break' it.
     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 and @exit=1
    begin
    if (condition)='your result'
    begin 
    set @exit=0
    end
    .
    .
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the pattern I usually use.

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM SomeCursor INTO ...
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;
    --some processing here
    IF <some-condition-here> = -1 BREAK;
    --some additional processing here
END;
```

Below is the more common pattern. Some prefer this method to avoid the control-of-flow inside the WHILE loop, but at the cost of an additional `FETCH`.  This is due to the lack of `DO...WHILE` in `T-SQL`.

```
FETCH NEXT FROM SomeCursor INTO ...
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --some processing here
    IF <some-condition-here> = -1 BREAK;
    --some additional processing here
    FETCH NEXT FROM SomeCursor INTO ...
END;
```

Comment: @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 means 'The FETCH statement failed or the row was beyond the result set.'  As i understand this not what the op means 'when condition false "Exit from a cursor loop" '

Comment: @Dudi Konifino, `BREAK` can be used to exit to loop under any condition.  I'll add an additional BREAK in the example to make this clearer.